# Is there a way to apply tags to cells in Excel, and calculate with those tags?

Tags: excel

I've never seen anything like this, but I thought of it and now I can't imagine why it's never been implemented before.

Think about CSS. You can apply "tags" of sorts (classes) to any element in HTML, and them with CSS, apply styling to any and all objects that might be of that class. You don't have to explicitly name them, the rendering engine just knows that everything with that class gets that style.

Now put that in excel. So basically you apply an attribute to a few cells, and then in an equation, do something like:
=SUM([ATTRIBUTE])

It's crazy how useful this would be.

So is this something that already exists in Excel, or no?
And if it's not already in excel, what could I possibly do to get the idea in the developer's heads?

Comment: The usual approach in Excel is to put the"tag" in an adjacent cell and then use *=SUMIF()*, etc.

Comment: [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) and [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing "Named Ranges" You can use Formulas>>Name Manager to set these up. Here's a quick way:

1. Highlight cells in your range.
   [image]
2. Use the little box up at the top left (the "Name Box")to give it a name (or use name manager).
   [image]
3. Do your `sum()`.
   [image]

You can reference these named ranges in VBA like `Range("mynewname")` and use them in conditional formatting and everywhere else you use a traditional range like `A1:A4`.

It would be cool if you give different types of arbitrary attributes to a cell or range, but a name really allows you to do that. You can just give names different prefixes like "id_teachers" vs "class_teachers" and then enforce how you use those throughout the rest of the sheet (like perhaps you only allow yourself to apply conditional formatting to class_ named objects, and only allow formulas to reference id_ named objects). It's all up to you.

Comment: Named ranges wouldn't really work for that. Mostly because you can only use a name on one cell.

Comment: That is not true at all. You can name a range, even one containing many areas.

Comment: For instance, you can set a named range to: `"=Sheet1!$E$6,Sheet1!$H$8,Sheet1!$H$14,Sheet1!$G$19,Sheet1!$C$21,Sheet1!$B$13,Sheet1!$B$7:$B$8"` That is not nearly as convenient as `<div name="blah"><span name="blah">...` but it's reasonably analogous.

Comment: I mean named ranges definitely work most of the way for that, but it's a huge hassle. I just think it would be a great thing for MS to implement. It would be nice to have a menu when you right click that basically has checkboxes, and allows you to apply various tags to the cell or range, create new tags, etc...